# url helper can not generate domain site

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I dockerize my laravel project.I use helper url() and request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() to get domain name in production ,but return container name.This helpers work in local but not work on server.this helper return mining-api.

services:

- api:

  - container_name: mining-api
  - build: ./agahmine_backend
  - working_dir: /var/www/html
  - restart: always
  - volumes:./agahmine_backend:/var/www/html
  - depends_on:
    db
    redis